# Ubuntu behaves as if I have two clipboards

Tags: linux, ubuntu, clipboard

My `Ctrl+V` produces a different result that `RightClick+Paste`

I can't reproduce this, it happens randomly, so I can't specify the circumstances just yet. I will as soon as I can make it happen all the time.

Please advise!

---

```
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 10.04.2 LTS
Release:    10.04
Codename:   lucid
```

Comment: Copy something, highlight something else, then try both paste methods.

Comment: Just tried this and got the exact same issue. Must be an Ubuntu bug.

Comment: holy kernel, you're right. is this addressable?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

X actually has [**three** clipboards](http://standards.freedesktop.org/clipboards-spec/clipboards-latest.txt). Highlighting text moves it into one clipboard (`PRIMARY`), then performing a copy operation copies it to a second (`CLIPBOARD`) (the third [`SECONDARY`] is almost never used). The two paste methods are using different clipboards, which is causing confusion on your part.

Comment: I guess i just won't use the explicit Copy clipboard ;) thanks for clearing this up

Comment: See also http://www.jwz.org/doc/x-cut-and-paste.html

Comment: Is it possible to consolidate the two paste boards?? This is such a constant frustration for me.