# Linux terminal: copy on select, paste on right click

Tags: unix, terminal

On my work pc I have putty and cygwin setup to copy when I select text, and paste on right click.

Have been trying to get that same combination working in ubuntu. Trying various terminal applications, but haven't found one that delivers.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Ben

Comment: Could it be the middle button that pastes?

Answer (score 1):

The convention with X is to [copy the selection to `PRIMARY` on select](https://superuser.com/a/272934/26316), and to paste from `PRIMARY` on middle-click.

Comment: Uhm .. some computers don't have a middle click

Comment: @rtconner: Well ain't that a damn shame...